# How to access Rails model attributes inside JavScript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, model

```rb
<%= form_for(@mymodel, remote: true, html: { id: 'match_form' }) do |f| %>
        <!-- I need to check if @mymodel.match_id matches the value generated by a controller function -->
   <%= f.submit 'Save', class: 'btn btn-primary', id: 'match_submit', style: "width:38px;padding:0px" %> 
   <%= button_tag 'Cancel', class: 'btn btn-secondary', id: 'match_cancel', style: "width:52px;padding:0px" %>
<% end%>


<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function() {
      $(document).on("click", "#match_submit", function(event){
        $.ajax('my_controller_method', {
          type: 'GET',
          dataType: 'script',
          data: {
            mid: $("#").val(),  // how do I pass @mymodel.match_id here?
          },
          error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          return console.log("AJAX Error: " + textStatus);
        }
      });      
    });
  </script>
```

I have a Rails form that represents a model as shown above.

How can I access attributes of the model inside the JavaScript code block shown above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use erb inside of javascript too:

```
mid: <%= @mymodel.match_id %>,
```

Or you can serialize your object with `gon` gem (https://github.com/gazay/gon)

Comment: Oh! I didn't know the `erb` tag/code will work inside JavaScript! I will definitely try!

Comment: @proton _ I have a related question here. I have posted the question here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60182085/how-to-return-value-from-a-rails-controller-method-during-an-ajax-call  WOuld you be able to help please? Thanks much!