# How to return value from a Rails controller method during an ajax call?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

```rb
<%= form_for(@mymodel, remote: true, html: { id: 'match_form' }) do |f| %>
        <!-- I need to check if @mymodel.match_id matches the value generated by a controller function -->
   <%= f.submit 'Save', class: 'btn btn-primary', id: 'match_submit', style: "width:38px;padding:0px" %> 
   <%= button_tag 'Cancel', class: 'btn btn-secondary', id: 'match_cancel', style: "width:52px;padding:0px" %>
<% end%>


<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function() {
      $(document).on("click", "#match_submit", function(event){
        $.ajax('my_controller_method', {
          type: 'GET',
          dataType: 'script',
          data: {
            mid: $("#").val(),  // how do I pass @mymodel.match_id here?
          },
          error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          return console.log("AJAX Error: " + textStatus);
        }
      });      
    });
  </script>
```

I have the above JavaScrpt code which makes an ajax call to a Rails controller method.

I would like to check if the value passed in this ajax call matches a certain value. If not, I would like to display a modal error message with only an `Ok` button.

I can think of 2 ways to achieve this:

1. I can return the correct value from the controller method (this requires some calculation by running a SQL query. That's why I am doing this in a controller method) and check the equality in JavaScript and throw a JavaScipt alert if there is no match.

   Q: For this I would like to know how I can return a number from a controller function (called during ajax call) back to the JavaScript
2. I could check for the match inside the controller itself and then render a bootstrap modal in the controller function itself

   Q: For this I would like to know how to render a bootstrap modal (which shows a text message and only an `Ok` button) inside my controller function.

Comment: after the `ajax` call return json answer with status and calculated value. And based on this value render or don't render modal window

Comment: Thanks much! Would you mind showing a code sample please? I am kinda new to this part of Rails. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I right understood your question.
I would rather prefer the second approach (because it has no sense to force a user press button if you can provide information without it).

```
<% if your_match_function or value %>
   <div> Ok </div>
<% else %>
   <script type="text/javascript"> 
      $('#myModal').modal('show')
   </script>
<% end %>
```

However, for the first approach, you can use the same too but render this snippet in a result of ajax request.
And don't forget to add HTML for a modal popup.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

Answer (score 0):

```
def my_controller_method
 # assign your value here like,
 @message = 'Error occured!'
end
```

make a js file as,

> my_controller_method.js.erb

in this js file do as,

```
$("#mymodaldiv").html("<%= j render(partial: 'my_partial_page',locals: {msg: @message}) %>");
```

Here, mymodaldiv is the id of the div that you have to put in your file from where AJAX call is happening as,

```
<div id='mymodaldiv'></div>
```

and my_partial_page is the name of your partial where you have to use msg variable to construct your page. as,

> _my_partial_page.html.erb

and code in the file _my_partial_page.html.erb goes like,

```
<h1><%= msg %></h1>
```